# Linux: list contents of sub directories with given name?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grep, ls

I'm using linux to analyze a windows directory structure. The structure is:

```
/Documents and settings
  /username1
    /My Documents
    ...
  /username2
    /My Documents
    ...
  ...
```

What command can I execute so that the contents (and sub folders) of all the "My Documents" directories are listed like:

```
/Documents and Settings/username1/My Documents/filename
/Documents and Settings/username1/My Documents/subdir/filename
/Documents and Settings/username2/My Documents/filename
```

Basically there are a ton of users but almost none have anything in their My Documents folder. I just want to find and show the contents of those user's that *do* have documents.

**EDIT:** Each "username" directory contains many sub directories. I only want to list the tree below the My Documents folder but do so for all usernames at once.

Answer (score 2):

Combining the first two answers, use find and ls -R:

find "/Documents and settings" -name "My Documents" -exec ls -R {} \;

This will find all of the *My Documents* directories and list everything underneath them, with full pathnames.  You need the quotes since the directory names have spaces in them.

Edit: An explination of how this works.  It starts at */Documents and settings*, looking for any file or directory that matches *My Documents*.  For each one it finds, it substitutes the path for {} in the ls.  The \; signifies the end of the command.

Comment: What does {} \; mean?

Comment: that command is throwing: "missing argument to -exec"

Comment: Make sure that you have the \; (backslash semicolon) on there.

Comment: Ah, once you explained I noticed I didn't have a space between '{}' and '\;'. Perfect. I assume the '\;' is to prevent the shell from expanding ';'?

Comment: Shoot, this is listing all the contents of Documents and Settings

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to the collection, ls -R doesn't really produce the nice output so I use **tree** command instead

```
find "/Documents and settings" -name "My Documents" -exec tree -f -i --noreport {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ls -R path_to_your_dir
```

or

```
ls -lR path_to_your_dir
```

for better view

However, best view is achieved with

```
find path_to_your_dir
```

NOTE: -R means recursive

Comment: see my edit, I only need the tree below each my documents folder. Not the tree below Documents and Settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command # find your_dir

Comment: see my edit, I only need the tree below each my documents folder. Not the tree below Documents and Settings.

Answer (score 0):

If you do want to see the pathname and don't want to have the full recursive -R listing, this seems to do roughly what you want, it's a little clunky though:

```
find . -type d -name '*Documents' ! -empty | (while read d; do echo $d; ls -la $d; done)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the recursive listing of files and folders under *Documents and Settings/User/My Documents*:

```
find Documents\ and\ Settings/*/My\ Documents -print
```

If you only want only the files and folders directly under Documents and Settings/User/My Documents:

```
ls -dr Documents\ and\ Settings/*/My\ Documents/*
```

The former will include a file like *Documents and Settings/User/My Documents/dir1/file1*, whereas the latter will list only *Documents and Settings/User/My Documents/dir1*